# Disable Plotpoint legend on hover in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Can someone tell me how to disable the legend which pops up when you hover over a plotpoint in Highcharts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a tooltip: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

You can set 'enabled':false